# Pass data from dynamic mat-cell to on-click function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table that I am using to display data being received from a service. One of the columns within this table displays a property `name` stored in the objects that are displayed in the table.

My table looks like this.

```
<table class="session-table" mat-table [dataSource]="sessions">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.sessionName}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.sessionDate}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="link">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Link</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.sessionLink}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Control</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="showDeleteModal()"><mat-icon><fa name="trash" size="lg"></fa></mat-icon></button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </table>
```

I want to be able to take the `name` property and pass it to the `showDeleteModal()` function that is called by the button in the fourth cell of each row. However I can't just access this data by doing `{{element.sessionName}}`, how else can I access this data and pass it to my function?

Comment: Wont passing element into the fn do the trick? Like this showDeleteModal(element)?

Comment: @Qellson That was the first thing I tried, but function is unresolved in this context.

Comment: and if you pass in row? since the html template variable for that block is row

Comment: @Qellson Yep, that's worked. Looks like I'm making things harder in my head than they need to be. Cheers.

Comment: No problem! Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `row` object in the function.

This should work:
`(click)="showDeleteModal(row)"`

Afterwards, you can retrieve name attribute like this:

```
showDeleteModal(row) {
   console.log(row.name);
}
```

Comment: You can also pass only the needed field: (click)="showDeleteModal(row.name)"

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to highlight that you may access any object property inside `showDeleteModal` function.